# Unable to set MBProgressHUD mode to determinate

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud

In a Swift 3 project I'm working on, I have a simple view controller with a `MBProgressHUD`. I can get the hud to show, and even though I set the mode property and the label's text, all I get is a spinning `UIActivityIndicator`. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
// Property declaration
var transferHUD = MBProgressHUD()


// Configured in viewDidLoad()
transferHUD = MBProgressHUD.init(view: self.view)
transferHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinate
transferHUD.hide(animated: false)


// from the progressUpdated function
transferHUD.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
transferHUD.label.text = "Transferring..."


// I logged the mode and this is what it said
// print("HUD mode -- \(transferHUD.mode)")
// Output == transferHUD mode -- MBProgressHUDMode


// Here is where I show it again. I've tried a few different ways, but neither way changes the appearance
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // self.transferHUD.show(animated: true)
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: `transferHUD` and `hud` ??? Seems you are using two different instance of mbprogresshud

Comment: I wish it was so simple. I was trying everything, from optional properties, hence the wrong name (unwrapped) `hud`.

Comment: You are hiding the hud in viewDidLoad, can you show the code where you are showing it back ?

Comment: Sure. It's updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `showAdded:`, it will create a new instance of MBProgressHUD. You can either call the show method or change the code like:

```
let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinate
hud.label.text = "Transferring..."
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I didn't add it as a subView before calling showAdded.